# PHP MySQL SELECT from 2 tables not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to select records from two tables.

Please see the screenshots for the table structures:

Table `listing`

[image: listing table]

Table `c_profile`

[image: c_profile]

I want to display  the records of listing table and few from c_profile table..

```
SELECT c_profile.c_name,c_profile.logo, c_profile.email, listing.id, listing.title, listing.type,listing.job_desc,listing.c_id, listing.time, listing.vote_up from c_profile,listing where c_uid=c_id
```

The above statement works fine but only problem is it doesn't select "vote_up" results.

However, if I use a normal SELECT statement without WHERE, it seems to work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Dont use the alias listing in listing.vote_up. If you need an alias, then specify one like this: select * from table t. In this case, t is the alias.

Comment: Is there any reasons or good or bad doing so ? I thought it is a referencing the table name not the alias as I am selecting from two tables  ... Thanks

Comment: You simply can't do select table.columnName from table. If you are going to do that, you need: select t.columnName from table t

Comment: @HkmSadekHossain not clear what you want

Comment: @Erick you simply can't doesn't really seem like a good reason? because i most certainly can?

Comment: Any chance this isn't a query issue but rather a "screen not wide enough to see everything" issue? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't show that column. What does `SELECT listing.vote_up from c_profile,listing where c_uid=c_id` show?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani, The statement SELECT everything only the "vote_up"  is not picked up . It shows 0 all the times !

Comment: @apokryfos  it shows vote_up with results 0 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a left join, because you want all the records of listing table and a few from c_profile table.

```
SELECT c_profile.c_name,
       c_profile.logo, 
       c_profile.email, 
       listing.id, 
       listing.title, 
       listing.type,
       listing.job_desc,
       listing.c_id, 
       listing.time, 
       listing.vote_up
FROM listing
LEFT JOIN c_profile ON c_uid=c_id
```

this way you keep all records for listing and only join where you can find a matching c_profile

Comment: No problem :) if you have anymore questions i'd be glad to help if not then don't forget to accept an answer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c_profile.c_name,c_profile.logo, c_profile.email, listing.id, listing.title, listing.type,listing.job_desc,listing.c_id, listing.time, listing.vote_up from listing left join c_profile ON c_profile.c_uid=listing .c_id